# JSON Object to POJO dynamically

Tags: java, json, pojo

I want to store an array of JSON Object into POJO class dynamically how can I do this particular thing in java.

```
[
{
"history":"L",
"loan":"12345"
"status":1
.
.
},
{
"History":"L",
"loan":"67890"
"status":1
.
.
},
....
]
```

Comment: you can create POJO class with same property and use jackson to map automatically. refer any spring boot rest api example to understand it better

Comment: Use below link to understand it https://dzone.com/articles/converting-json-to-pojos-using-java

Comment: i have done that currently but i wanna do it directly on basis of Body Response without evening seeing the response JSON keys

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a model calss.
lets say your json-string is like this :

```
String temp_json_string = "{ \"history\":\"L\", \"loan\":\"12345\", \"status\":\"1\"}";
```

Go to this or similar site and generate a class for your temp_json_string by pasting json string in that link and get class, choose getters and setters if you need.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Create a new gson/jackson object (import that library either maven or build jre system path), convert the string to this "BankLoanDetails" class.

```
    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    BankLoanDetails my_loan_pojo = gson.fromJson(temp_json_string, 
                                                   BankLoanDetails.class);
```

your my_loan_pojo is pojo representing your json string.

Did you check at [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I am extending Akash's answer.

```java
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory;

---

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<DTO> list = mapper.readValue(JSONString, TypeFactory.collectionType(List.class, DTO.class));
```

Comment: What if i give JSON obj as parameter instead of string will this work and what is DTO.class

Answer (score -1):

First Create a POJO Class something like this:

```java
public class Loan {
    private String history;
    private String loan;
    private int status;

    \\ generate getters,setters and toString method 
}
```

Now parse your json and convert into jSONArray (import json-simple library),

```java
        String path = "path to your json file";
        File f = new File(path);
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(f));
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
```

Now

1. Create a new ObjectMapper's object (import jackson-databind library),
2. convert parsed JSONArray to json string using writeValueAsString method,
3. and again convert it into list of "Loan" Class.

```java
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonArray);
        List<Loan> loanList = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Loan[].class));
        for (Loan l : loanList)
            System.out.println(l);
```

> Note : your json array contains different keys as history(first
>   object) and History(second object). change it to history as in Loan
>   class, data member is history.